# htaccess rule to redirect user without page name

Tags: .htaccess

My `index.php` page redirect to this type of url after process `results.php?token=0e635edc03`.

Now I would to to hide the `results.php`. So just: `domain.com/0e635edc03`.

Do I need a `.htaccess` rule ?

Which `.htaccess` rule I need to perform it ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-f]+)$ /results.php?token=$1 [L,NC]
```

now you need to make sure the index.php file redirects to `domain.com/0e635edc03` instead of the results.php URL.